# How to Stop Refresh View if child using environment object

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
struct MainView:View  
  var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
                ImgView()..
      }
  ChildView()
}// VStack ends here 

struct ChildView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var obj: OBJJ
```

So as I am performing `EnvironmentObject` in `ChildView` then my `ImgView()` getting refresh every time. how can I stop it ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. It's not possible right now to tell what the connection is between these elements.

Comment: Yes, please provide more code, but the answer is probably "you can't". If the environment object changes and causes a refresh of `ChildView` then SwiftUI will need to redraw the view hierarchy. That's the way it works. Views are ephemeral.